# Override custom-logo parameters in WordPress child theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm making a child theme based off of [Shapely](https://colorlib.com/wp/themes/shapely/). In Shapely's `functions.php`, custom-logo support is declared.

```
/**
     * Add support for the custom logo functionality
     */
    add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', array(
        'height'     => 55,
        'width'      => 136,
        'flex-width' => true,
    ) );
```

In my child theme's `functions.php`, I tried writing:

```
function override_shapely_customlogo() {
    add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', array(
       'width'      => 168,
       'flex-height' => true,
    ) );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'override_shapely_customlogo' );
```

But this doesn't appear to do anything.

Is there a way for a child theme to override custom logo support parameters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Took a bit of digging and I definitely encountered some false leads, but I got there. Turns out that you can absolutely override `theme_support` functions. However, your code has the exact same priority and action hook as Shapely's, so whichever code executes last wins out.

And (here's the bit that took some research) the `functions.php` of a child theme actually gets executed *before* the parent theme's:

> [T]he functions.php of a child theme does not override its counterpart
>   from the parent. Instead, it is loaded in addition to the parent’s
>   functions.php. **(Specifically, it is loaded right before the parent’s
>   file.)**

[From the Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#using-functions-php), emphasis mine. Therefore, all we have to do is give your code a higher level of execution priority.

```php
<?php
function override_shapely_customlogo() {
        add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', array(
             'width'      => 168,
             'flex-height' => true,
        ) );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'override_shapely_customlogo', 11 );
?>
```

Edit: just wanted to add, the reason why I went with priority `11` here is that `10` is the default priority on `add_action()`: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/#parameters

Comment: This didn't seem to make a difference. Is there a way to determine what level of priority my parent function(s) would be firing at?

Comment: I actually set up the Shapely theme and can say that the above code *should* be working for you. Very curious it doesn't. Shapely's parent functions fire at the default priority. A way to force your function to take the higher priority is to change the hook it's bound to. So, change `after_setup_theme` to `init`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Perhaps I have a typo somewhere, I'll try to see what's up.

Comment: I'm a dummy and was putting your code in `styles.css` by mistake. Your answer solved my problem and I have now marked it as correct.